# Refresh a tab in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, tabs

Is there a way to refresh a tab's content in XCode?  I'm setting a tab as follows:         [[dappDelegate tabBarController] setSelectedIndex:1];

However, when I try and do it from a different screen, the same tab screen is still selected.  Is there a way to have the tab completely reload the data?

Thanks, Graeme.

Answer (score 0):

I use a hack around that seems to work for my case:

```
if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1)
{
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:-1];
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
else
{
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  On my button click in a different tab, I added the above code.  However, it still behaves at it did before.  The view still doesn't reload =[  Should the code go somewhere else?

Comment: I was really basing this off a UISegmentControl i was just messing with, but the theory should still work for tab bar, I believe the code i posted above will get the UIViewController in index 1 to call viewWillAppear: again and in there you allow for updating the view, if that makes sense. it still could depend on the type of controller  though.

Comment: Yah, I'm trying to do it via the tabBarController.  Is there any other code I need to call besides setSelectedIndex when changing to a different screen in a tab bar?

Comment: you can maybe use the UITabBarControllerDelegate method didSelectViewController:. I'm not at work anymore so I don't have my projects in front of me.

Comment: I was messing with that right now actually =)  http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/4323-tabbarcontroller-content-refresh-howto.html  Sounds like the problem I was having.  However, that solution didn't work for me.  I tried removing the controller, and readding it etc etc,  But still nothing =/  Thanks for the responses